# Timus Online Judge Problem 1001 - "Reverse Root"

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

The problem statement can be found [here](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001).

Description (short):

**Input**

The input stream contains a set of integer numbers \$A_i\$ (\$0 \le A_i \le 10^{18}\$). The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.

**Output**

For each number \$A_i\$ from the last one until the first one, you should output its square root. Each square root should be printed in a separate line with at least four digits after the decimal point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double t;
    double v [128 * 1024];
    int idx = 0;
    while (cin >> t) {
        v[idx] = sqrt(t);
        ++idx;
    }

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(4);

    for (int i = idx - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << v[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am encountering a TLE on test case 9, with an execution time of 2.031s and memory usage of 1 474 KB.  (The allowable limits are 2.0s and 64 MB.)  How can I improve (or change) my method to complete the problem successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The input stream contains a set of integer numbers \$A_i\$ (\$0 \leq A_i \leq 10^{18}\$).

So you should change

```
double t;
```

to

```
unsigned long long t;
```

This actually speeds up the program a lot.

---

To speed up the output, instead of

```
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(4);

for (int i = idx - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    cout << v[i] << endl;
```

Try

```
for (int i = idx - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%.4f\n", v[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why does changing `double` to `unsigned long long` speed up the program (after I made these modifications I got AC)? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: well the question was marked C++ so recommending printf seems not right. instead maybe one should turn on buffering of output of cout if printing speed is a problem.

Comment: @manan I would guess it's because for `double` it will correctly parse things like `1e5`, and so is more complicated. I don't really know C++ though, perhaps someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

Some cycles *might* be shaved off by making `v` global, and/or replacing index increment/decrement with a pointer increment/decrement. For a smart compiler with necessary optimization turned on it would make no difference; do you know how do they compile the submissions?

As for the review, the code is OK except

- [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), which is not OK.
- Possible buffer overflow when number of integers exceeds \$2^{18}\$ (I know they promised, but for code review it is a red flag)
- Misbehaving on a malformed input (see above...)

Comment: Thanks! Is `using namespace std` generally not ok, or is it acceptable for contest programming? I read the linked answer and it seemed to be discussing larger programs where serious maintenance would be necessary.

Comment: It is a bad habit. The sooner you drop it, the better.